# Dot Product between 2 matrices in ruby, most efficient way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, matrix, gradient-descent

I am writing a machine learning algorithm in ruby that uses gradient descent and logistic regression.

The algorithms works fine, except that in ruby the dot product between matrices is very slow.

I started using a gem RubyPython that allows you to import python libraries like `numpy` into ruby and use it's functions.

The performance of `numpy` is impressive. The application started to run 1000% faster, except that i always get `segmentation fault` halfway.

Does anyone know any other way to speed up the dot product of 2 matrices in ruby?

Comment: How are you doing it in ruby, without the numpy stuff that is?

Comment: There are lots of ruby gems for this, without having to muck about with Python inside Ruby.  Have you tried them?  I would try and avoid RubyPython if possible.  Eg https://github.com/SciRuby/nmatrix and http://rb-gsl.rubyforge.org/

Comment: i tried installing nmatrix and it always fails, I believe because it is missing ATLAS and I can not install ATLAS in MAC-OSX. Always errors out. I will give a try at rb-gsl. Thanks @MaxWilliams

Comment: Until I read your comment on @Leon's answer I assumed you were using the `Matrix` class, in part because you said, "...the dot product between matrices...`.

Comment: Yes i was using the Matrix class in the way `(a*b)` where a and b were the Matrices, but the Vector inner_product is super fast.

Comment: This any use? (installing ATLAS on Snow Leopard)  http://okomestudio.net/biboroku/?p=722

Comment: I tried this one too, did not help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby actually has a built in `matrix` library. You can use it by calling

```
require 'matrix'
```

You create a vector object and take the inner product of it. For example, let's create two vectors

```
a = Vector[1,3,-5]
b = Vector[4,-2,-1]

a.inner_product(b)
=> 3
```

Comment: Vector speeds it up a lot. Thanks

Comment: `Vector.send(:new,existing_array)` - the only way to use it with a variable rather than hardcoding an array?

Comment: @xxjjnn You can do `Vector.elements(existing_array)`